# Can't create dbo schema

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have been searching a lot for a solution for my problem but haven't find
any.

The problem is when I create schema dbo I get below error.

```
CREATE SCHEMA dbo;
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
Msg 2759, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.
```

Some explanation I use a product called DbWrench for database design and when
the design is ready a generate the script which create all the objects that are missing in the MSSQL database that I'm connected to.
So the problem as I mentioned is the above  statement CREATE SCHEMA dbo;

In the generated script is the first statement CREATE SCHEMA dbo;

So even if I log in as administrator and run this statement CREATE SCHEMA dbo; 
from within SQL Server I get the same error.

Here is just the first rows in the script that will be run agains the connected
MSSQL Server

```
USE DiseMSSQL_new;

CREATE SCHEMA dbo;
```

Comment: In MS SQL Server you can't create dbo schema because it is already created by default.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem, though I wasn't using DbWrench. I use SSMS with SQL Server 2012. As for me, I found that the schema **dbo** was already created under *Security > Schemas* when I created the database. So there was no need for me to create a separate schema **dbo**. I created functions and stored procedures easily under that schema.